# Could not read all bytes from /dev/ttyS0

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, serial, uart, raspbian-buster

I try to send some data to a module which connected via UART **/dev/ttyS0**, I send a standard command to module and module send me back a 13 bytes acknowledgment, but the first 5 bytes of ack not received.

I checked my code by using USB to TTL module and all things are correct the 13 bytes acknowledgment totally received, but when I using Raspberry PI UART my problem still remains.

Is this problem related to any configuration in Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Ah let me see.  There are many possible causes: (1) You "standard" command is not that standard to the module which need special starting control characters such as <Ctrl C> three times, or a special start character which happens to be the 6th character in your command. If you give me a link to your standard command set, then I can see if there is any problem. Or you might try to use the "loopback" test to check out if your Rpi serial port can echo every character sent.  See the references in the following file for more details. https://penzu.com/p/898abc20.

Comment: Make sure the default serial port console on Uart0 is off (use `raspi-config`->advanced)

Comment: first 5 or last five? always 5? autobaud used?

Comment: @tlfong01Thanks for your comment, I connect to fingerprint module, I send a command to ask module the number of enrolled fingerprints on the module, I got the correct result but cannot get the first five bytes of acknowledgment.
to answer your second question always first 5 bytes missing. What is autobaud?

Comment: @PMF how can I figure out? I cannot find anything in `raspi-config->advanced`

Comment: @ParsaKarami: Sorry, It's raspi-config -> Interfacing Options -> Serial. Say "No" to the first prompt (serial console), but say yes to the second prompt (enable serial port). Then reboot.

Comment: @PMF I do stuff, but not working yet :(